# Converting last n digits of a number to Zero

Tags: python

What is the best way to replace the last digits of a number to zero keeping first three digits as it is, in python?

Example:

```
23456789 -> 23400000
112022 -> 112000
1111-> 1110
111 -> 111 (no conversion)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`round` accepts a negative argument, which is quite useful, but it rounds the result, which may not be exactly what you want:

```
a = 23456789
round(a, -4)
```

#### outputs:

```
23460000
```

**If you do not wish to round**, you could use a small helper function, maybe like this one:

```
import math

def significant(num, signum):

    expo = 10**(int(math.log(num, 10)) - signum + 1)
    return expo * (num // expo)

significant(12345, 3)
```

#### outputs:

```
12300
```

Comment: Note this is rounding, doesn't give expected output, i.e. 2346... instead of 2345....

Comment: yes, you are correct @jpp - round with a negative number is rather useful though. I added a short helper that returns a number with the specified significant digits.

Answer (score 4):

convert it to a string:

```
a = 23456789

a_str = str(a)

sol = a_str[0:3]+"0"*(len(a_str)-3)

print(sol)
```

returns: 23400000

Answer (score 2):

Use `round`, but you have to be a bit more clever to get the functionality you want

```
def round_n(num, keep=3):
    return round(num, keep - len(str(num)))


round_n(23456789)
Out[72]: 23500000

round_n(112022)
Out[73]: 112000

round_n(1111)
Out[74]: 1110

round_n(111)
Out[75]: 111
```

---

n.b this will only work with integers, not floats

---

If you just want to truncate, not round, then instead do

```
def truncate_int(n, keep=3):
   if n < 0:  # account for '-'
       keep += 1
   s = str(n)
   return int(s[:keep] + '0'*(len(s) - keep))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a converter function using `math.log10`, floor division and exponentials:

```
a = 23456789
b = 112022
c = 1111
d = 111

import math

def converter(x, k=3):
    dig = int(math.log10(x)) + 1
    n = dig - k
    return x // 10**n * 10**n

for val in [a, b, c, d]:
    print(val, '->', converter(val))

23456789 -> 23400000
112022 -> 112000
1111 -> 1110
111 -> 111
```

Comment: FWIW, `log10` is faster for numbers with _lots_ of digits, otherwise `len(str(n))` beats it.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Nice to know! Hadn't timed it myself.

Comment: On my machine the cutoff point is around 30 decimal digits, YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

```
n - n%1000
```

For a positive integer `n`, `n%1000` gives you the value of the last three digits. So subtracting that will give you a number ending in `000`.

```
>>> n = 12345
>>> n - n%1000
12000
```

If you want to do this for other numbers of digits, you can do it like this:

```
>>> n = 1234567
>>> r = 10**5 # I want to zero-out five digits
>>> n - n%r
1200000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using floor division and multiplication with an appropriate multiplier. That way, we avoid problems with rounding. We also have to ensure that the multiplier is an integer. We can do that by using `max` to force `m` to be non-negative.

```
data = (23456789, 112022, 1111, 111, 6, 98, 987, 9876, 9876598765)

def zero_final(n, digits=3):
    m = 10 ** max(0, len(str(n)) - digits)
    return n // m * m

for n in data:
    print(n, zero_final(n))
```

**output**

```
23456789 23400000
112022 112000
1111 1110
111 111
6 6
98 98
987 987
9876 9870
9876598765 9870000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way,

but I would use string manipulation and formatting.

```
number = 23456789
print int(str(number)[:3] + "%0{0}d".format(len(str(number)) - 3) % 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using string operation as follows:

```
def number_cov(num):
    x = str(num)
    if len(x)>3:
        cov_num = int(x[0:3]+'0'*(len(x)-3))
    else:
        cov_num = num
    return cov_num

number_cov(11111)
11100
```